# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch $Proxy0.joinNetwork(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, rmi

Here is my code:

```
public class PeerNode extends UnicastRemoteObject implements PeerInterface {

    private PeerInterface joint;
    private List<PeerNode> neighbours;
    public PeerNode(String s, int idnumber) throws IOException {
        PeerNode.setNome(s);
        PeerNode.setKey(idnumber);
        this.neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Peer node initialized");
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public void contactExistingNode(String node) throws Exception, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        System.out.println("I know the peer "+ node);
        System.out.println("I try to join automatically the network");
        joint = (PeerInterface) registry.lookup(node);
        joint.joinNetwork(this);
    }
```

And this is the interface:

```
public interface PeerInterface extends Remote {

    public void joinNetwork(PeerNode p) throws RemoteException;

}
```

I'm trying to pass the object remote peer... and at this line

```
joint.joinNetwork(this);
```

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
...
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.joinNetwork(Unknown Source)
at com.server.PeerNode.contactExistingNode(PeerNode.java:41)
at com.server.Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

I already casted this as PeerInterface, PeerNode... but it doesn't work.
Someone can help me? 
This is the class who receive the object

```
public void joinNetwork(PeerNode p) throws RemoteException {
    neighbours.add(p);
}
```

Comment: What if you change the method to public void joinNetwork(PeerInterface p) throws RemoteException ?

Comment: I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client doesn't have an instance of the remote object. It has an instance of the remote interface.  The signature of the remote method should be

```
void joinNetwork(PeerInterface peer) throws RemoteException;
```

Fix your remote interface, your remote object, and your client; recompile; redeploy; and retest.

Comment: Hello there. Thanks for the answer... They help me and i fixed it. I've already tried to to that but it hadn't work till i change also this: private List<PeerInterface> neighbours;